# Assembly Language Check Login

Tags: assembly

```
.model small
.stack
.data
  a db "Hello$"
  login db "Please Log in: $"
  lg db ?
  helloMsg db 0dh, 0ah, "Hello Message$"

.code
main proc
  mov ax, @data
  mov ds, ax

  mov ah, 09h
  lea dx, login
  int 21h

  mov ah, 0ah
  int 21h
  mov lg, bl

  mov cx, 5
  mov si, 0
ck: 
  mov ah, 02h
  mov dl, [a+si]
  mov bl, [lg+si]
  cmp dl, bl
  je hi
  int 21h
  inc si
  loop ck
  jne bye


hi:
  mov ah, 09h
  lea dx, helloMsg
  int 21h

bye:
  mov ah, 4ch
  int 21h



main endp
  end main
```

I have tried to logging into the system and using the cmp command to compare the input and the id I declare "Hello", I don't know whats wrong with my coding cannot compare here. From Diploma Student

Comment: I need some help...

Comment: May i ask any different with a db 'H','e','l','l','o',0 and a db "Hello$" ??

Comment: I would recommend using a debugger to trace through your code.

Comment: Ops, Please help me TT... Thanks a lot TT

Comment: Check how [Int 21/AH=0Ah](http://www.ctyme.com/intr/rb-2563.htm) must be used. You aren't setting the input buffer, `lg` is a byte only, `bl` isn't anything useful, you are confusing conditional jumps (probably, I didn't check deep) and you are checking that the *n-th* char is equal to the *n-th* char of "Hello".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to capture a string from keyboard with `int 21h`, `ah=0ah`, you need to declare a variable with three sections: the first byte to specify the maximum number of chars allowed (max length), one second byte where the interrupt will store the number of chars that the user entered, and an array of chars, the length of this array must match the maximum chars allowed, **plus one**, because the user will finish with ENTER key (char 0dh = 13), this key is stored too.

After the input is captured, the user string (variable `a`) must be compared to the array of chars (the third section of the input variable).

Next code has comments to help you understand :

```
.model small
.stack 100h
.data
  a db "Hello$"
  login db "Please Log in: $"
  lg db 21          ;<=== MAXIMUM NUMBER OF CHARS ALLOWED (20).
     db ?           ;<=== NUMBER OF CHARS THAT USER ENTERED (?).
     db 21 dup(0)   ;<=== ARRAY OF CHARS (FINISH WITH 0DH=13).
  helloMsg db 0dh, 0ah, "Hello Message$"

.code
main proc
  mov ax, @data
  mov ds, ax

  mov ah, 09h
  lea dx, login
  int 21h

  mov ah, 0ah
  MOV DX, OFFSET lg     ;<=== TELL INT 21H TO STORE CAPTURED STRING HERE.
  int 21h

  MOV SI, OFFSET LG + 2 ;<=== POINT TO THE ARRAY OF CHARS.
  MOV DI, OFFSET A      ;<=== POINT TO THE USER.
ck: 
;CHECK END OF USER.  
  MOV DH, [DI]
  CMP DH, '$'
  JE  hi                ;<=== END REACHED. ALL CHARS MATCH.

;CHECK END OF INPUT.  
  MOV DL, [SI]          ;<=== CURRENT ENTERED CHAR.
  CMP DL, 13
  JE  bye               ;<=== END REACHED. INPUT IS SHORTER.

;COMPARE CURRENT ENTERED CHAR TO CURRENT USER CHAR.  
  CMP DL, DH
  jne bye               ;<=== CURRENT CHARS ARE DIFFERENT.
  INC SI                ;<== NEXT ENTERED CHAR.
  INC DI                ;<== NEXT USER CHAR.
  JMP CK                ;<== REPEAT.

hi:
  mov ah, 09h
  lea dx, helloMsg
  int 21h

bye:
  mov ah, 4ch
  int 21h

main endp
  end main
```

Four cases must be considered when comparing :

1. Both strings (user and captured) are equal. Example: "Hello" - "Hello".
2. Strings are different. Example: "Hello" - "Stackoverflow".
3. The user string is shorter. Example: "Hello" - "Hellox".
4. The entered string is shorter. Example: "Hello" - "Hell".

Previous program handles cases 1, 2 and 4. For example, if the user enters "Hell", the program detects both strings are not the same thing.

For case 3, when user enters "Hellox", the program says both strings are equal, which is not true. This happens because the comparation loop repeats until one of the strings ends, in this case, the user string ends before (it's shorter). I will leave the program like this because I don't want to make it more complicated, you can try to make it work for case 3. Anyway, if you really really want the program to handle case 3, I will make the change, it will require two more comparations.