# Assembly login program always returning "true"

Tags: assembly

I'm working on my presentation and I came across to this code that is great addition to my presentation. The problem is if I enter "Hello123" (for example), the program assumes the "Hello123" and "Hello" is matched.

This code came from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39041534/assembly-language-check-login/39045777#39045777). I wasn't able to comment to his code because of my low rep. I did research and tried to do it myself but I can't sort it out the problem. I would be very grateful if anyone can help me.

```
.model small
.stack 100h
.data
    a db "Hello$"
    login db "Please Log in: $"
    lg db 21          ;<=== MAXIMUM NUMBER OF CHARS ALLOWED (20).
       db ?           ;<=== NUMBER OF CHARS THAT USER ENTERED (?).
       db 21 dup(0)   ;<=== ARRAY OF CHARS (FINISH WITH 0DH=13).
    helloMsg db 0dh, 0ah, "Hello Message$"

.code
main proc
mov ax, @data
mov ds, ax

mov ah, 09h
lea dx, login
int 21h

mov ah, 0ah
MOV DX, OFFSET lg     ;<=== TELL INT 21H TO STORE CAPTURED STRING HERE.
int 21h

MOV SI, OFFSET LG + 2 ;<=== POINT TO THE ARRAY OF CHARS.
MOV DI, OFFSET A      ;<=== POINT TO THE USER.
ck: 
;CHECK END OF USER.  
MOV DH, [DI]
CMP DH, '$'
JE  hi                ;<=== END REACHED. ALL CHARS MATCH.

;CHECK END OF INPUT.  
MOV DL, [SI]          ;<=== CURRENT ENTERED CHAR.
CMP DL, 13
JE  bye               ;<=== END REACHED. INPUT IS SHORTER.

;COMPARE CURRENT ENTERED CHAR TO CURRENT USER CHAR.  
CMP DL, DH
jne bye               ;<=== CURRENT CHARS ARE DIFFERENT.
INC SI                ;<== NEXT ENTERED CHAR.
INC DI                ;<== NEXT USER CHAR.
JMP CK                ;<== REPEAT.

hi:
mov ah, 09h
lea dx, helloMsg
int 21h

bye:
mov ah, 4ch
int 21h

main endp
 end main
```

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: Oh, sorry. How to avoid the program to return "true" if I input "Hello123"? because the password is "Hello".

Comment: As it is, the code only checks whether the input is shorter, not whether it's longer. So anything that begins with the password is accepted.

Comment: Yeah, that's the problem.

Comment: so fix it.  If you reach the end of one string and the other string is not at its end, the terminator doesnt match, then why call that a pass?

Comment: I'm trying. I added some check string length before "ck:" but still no avail.

Comment: Hash the strings and compare those...

Comment: Terminate correct password `a` with `13` (enter) (no need to use `'$'`, as you don't print the password with `int 21h,ah=9` service, and also this will allow you to use `$` as regular part of password). Then load length of user input from `LG+1` into `cl` (or `cx`, but zero-extend the 8 bit value into 16b). Keep comparing both strings until they have different character, or until you decrement `cl` to -1 (no more characters in input, including the `13` byte).

Comment: Omg. I'm so dumb. Thank you to anyone! The code I'm missing is: 
cmp byte ptr lg + 1, 5

Comment: Yes, that's one of possible solutions (probably the simplest one), but that requires you to update the length whenever the password is modified, plus if you would read the password from some encrypted storage, not available to somebody reverse-engineering it, having the `5` value in the source will give them hint about how the correct password looks (5 chars long). If you will make the "enter" part of value to be compared against, you can have more universal code for the check, without hard-coded length. So the simplest solutions have sometimes their own drawbacks... :)

Comment: Thank you! I'll keep that in mind. This will be my first part of my presentation (I'm working with another program. :) and thinking to combine it all into one) to our class. I can understand the code and I can explain it to them how it works (Just need time). But I'm afraid we'll not going any deeper on the assembly language 'cause our presentation will be the last part of our class. Again, Thank you! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So much time burned not knowing that only one line of code could end it all.

```
cmp byte ptr lg + 1, 5
```

add that before ck:

```
ck: 
;CHECK END OF USER.  
MOV DH, [DI]
CMP DH, '$'
JE  hi                ;<=== END REACHED. ALL CHARS MATCH.
```